# How to use global JS variable inside AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use a JavaScript variable created globally (inside index.html file `head` section) inside my angularJS controller.  Unfortunately, I also have to use grunt to create a minified version of every file in my project, and so variable assignments get altered.

What should be along the lines of this:

```
$scope.adminName = adminName (global variable set in head)
```

ends up becoming something like:

```
var a = e;
```

Or some BS like that.  I cannot post the example due to restrictions placed on us.  But basically, how do you pass a global JavaScript variable into an AngularJS controller while also ensuring that during the minification process (when variable names get altered), it's still valid.

Comment: Minification should properly respect global vars. If you are seeing it get lost, something is messed up with the minification.

Comment: Try `window.variable`.